# Error "String contains an invalid character" in angular 6 application

Tags: firefox, angular7, angular-routing

I have made an 7 angular application. and I use firefox nightly to run this application.

But when I run the application with `ng serve -o` I get an error:

```
ERROR DOMException: "String contains an invalid character" AppComponent.html:1
ERROR CONTEXT 
Object { view: {…}, nodeIndex: 1, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…} }
DOMException: "String contains an invalid character"
```

```
<!-- app.component.html -->
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>

// router
[
    {path: '', component: HomeComponent}
]
```

> This error just appear on firefox nightly and firefox for developers

Answer (score 2):

Just had a similar error - It is not easy to track down just having this error message.

**In general:**
First try to localize the lines failing for instance by temporarely deleting random parts of HTML of Component in question and find the culprit - when this is done you can ask or already have a clue how to fix.

**In my case:**
I just copy & pasted code from TS to HTML-File with semicolon inside like:

```
<app-sequence-live
  (voteDoOverride)="voteDoOverride($event)";
></app-sequence-live>
```

Fixed:

```
<app-sequence-live
  (voteDoOverride)="voteDoOverride($event)"
></app-sequence-live>
```